# Create a swipeable view within a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I want a view inside my viewController (half the screen) which will act like a PageViewController and will allow me to swipe left and right between a couple of views.

I can't seem to find anything on how to achieve this.

Would I need to use a view which is linked to a pageViewController, which is linked to 2 different viewControllers, all of which are the same size as the view in my app that I want to be swipeable?

Any help or literature on this would be useful.

[image]

Comment: You can add a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to a UIView

Comment: Your question may not be that clear, can you please post a screenshot or a rough sketch as to what you are trying to achieve? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you need a containerView in the parent, and embed page view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a sliding carousel type thing that displays UIViews and UIPageViewController requires you to provide separate controllers which you don't want to do.

You can achieve this with UICollectionViewController, however I would recommend you look into [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel).

Using this library with the linear carousel option and providing a view that is the  same width as the screen, I believe you will be able to achieve what you want to achieve.